# JS or jQuery - getting both key and value of the dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this HTML for a DropDownList (that relates to a model with simple `int Id` and `string Name`)

```
<select id="Powder_Id" name="Powder.Id">
    <option value="1">50g</option>
    <option value="2">100g</option>
</select>
```

I can get the selected option **key** (`Id`) using this JS:

```
function save() {
    var payload = {
        DdlId: $("#Powder_Id").val()  // e.g. 1 or 2
    };
```

But how can I get the selected option **value** (`Name`)? Something like SelectedValue in place of `val()`?:

```
function saveSummary() {
    var p = {
        Powder: { Id: $("#Powder_Id").SelectedValue } // e.g. "50g" or "100g"
    }
```

Ideally I want to recreate the model as an object to pass to an ajax call, but to do that I need both the `Id` and `Name` values.

Comment: [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) elements don't have keys and values. They have values and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected text by

```
$("#Powder_Id option:selected").text();
```

```js
 var selectedText = $("#Powder_Id option:selected").text();
 console.log(selectedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Powder_Id" name="Powder.Id">
    <option value="1">50g</option>
    <option value="2">100g</option>
</select>
```